# AvatarGroup of bordered Avatars?

Tags: material-ui

Fairly new to MUI, trying to create an AvatarGroup where each avatar has a border. The effect I'm looking for is something like this:
[image: Overlapping avatars]

I'm able to give individual avatars a border, but when wrapped in a group, the borders don't draw.  So this code:

```
            <Avatar
           sx={{
              width: 32,
              height: 32,
              typography: 'body2',
              color: 'text.primary',
              border: 1,
              borderColor: 'text.primary',
              bgcolor: 'background.paper',
           }}
        >
           DC
        </Avatar>
        <Avatar
           sx={{
              width: 32,
              height: 32,
              typography: 'body2',
              color: 'info.main',
              border: 1,
              borderColor: 'info.main',
              bgcolor: 'background.paper',
           }}
        >
           A
        </Avatar>
```

draws like this: [image]

But wrap it in an AvatarGroup and it draws like this: [image].

TIA for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<AvatarGroup 
  sx={{ ["& .MuiAvatarGroup-avatar"]: { borderColor: "inherit" } }}
>
  <Avatar 
    sx={{
    width: 32,
    height: 32,
    typography: 'body2',
    color: 'text.primary',
    border: 1,
    borderColor: 'text.primary',
    bgcolor: 'background.paper',
  }}
  >
    DC    
  </Avatar>
  <Avatar
    sx={{
    width: 32,
    height: 32,
    typography: 'body2',
    color: 'info.main',
    border: 1,
    borderColor: 'info.main',
    bgcolor: 'background.paper',
  }}      
  >
    A
  </Avatar>
</AvatarGroup>
```

[avatar-group](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/avatar-group/)

In the browser debugger, open the Elements tab and select your element,
on the right side of the panel you will see a hierarchy of CSS classes, in it you can find the class that overrides your parameters.